# ASSERT : "!d->isWidget" in file kernel\qobject.cpp, line 2003 (Qt Creator 5.0.2, C++)

Tags: c++, qt, assert, qobject

So I had this basic class "Jeton" :

```
class Jeton: public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Jeton(const unsigned int r, const unsigned int v, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    unsigned int getNbJetons() const{ return nbJetons;}
    unsigned int getRang() const{ return rang;}
    void changeNbJetons(const unsigned int nb){nbJetons = nb;}

private:
    unsigned int rang; 
    unsigned int nbJetons;
    QPixmap* imgJeton;

signals:
    void jetonClicked(Jeton*);

public slots:
public slots:
    void clickedEvent(){ emit jetonClicked(this); }
};
```

And another class called "PiocheJetons" which then created some Jeton objects.
However, I tried to move this declaration :

```
layoutJetons = new QVBoxLayout();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        nbJetons[i] = new QLCDNumber;
        jetons[i] = new Jeton(i, 6);

        nbJetons[i]->display((int)jetons[i]->getNbJetons());

        connect(jetons[i], SIGNAL(jetonClicked(Jeton*)), this, SLOT(jetonClique(Jeton*)));

        layoutJetons->addWidget(jetons[i]);
        layoutJetons->addWidget(nbJetons[i]);
    }
```

Originally in the "PiocheJetons" constructor, to my main class.
My issue here is the fact it worked but it does not work anymore and provide the error of the title of this post.

If you can help me, I would be grateful!
Thanks,

Victor

Comment: Too less details. I think the error is coming up in run time; in this case which line of your code is the one calling the function which then assert? You should be able to understand it in run time looking at the call stack

Comment: The code `!d->isWidget` only appears in one place in qobject.cpp namely in `QObject::setParent()`. It is to make sure `QObject::setParent()` is not called for widgets probably because they must call `QWidget::setParent()`. Still it remains unclear what could trigger such a situation.

Comment: Looks like, according to the debugger, it is the `this->addLayout(layoutJetons)` in my main window... The strange part is that, as I said, it worked when being called from the old PiocheJetons constructor.